# Mercurial purge command only deleting deepest child folder in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, mercurial, mercurial-extension, purge

I am using the purge command in Windows for Mercurial (purge is a bundled extension) to delete all untracked and ignored files from the repository.

```
hg purge --all
```

However, it is showing weird behaviour in where it will only delete the deepest child folder in a scenario where you have a parent and a child folder, both of which are ignored.

Thus I have to run the above command multiple times (sometimes 6-7 times in a row), before it deletes all non-tracked and ignore files.

Why is this occurring?

Comment: I've not seen that behaviour. What version of Mercurial are you using?

Comment: you could use a dos for loop with the command `hg st -nui`

Comment: I'm using Mercurial Distributed SCM v2.2.1.